# How to have a range in a MySQL If statement?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a select that calculates affiliate payouts.

my approach is pretty simple.

```
SELECT
 month(payments.timestmap)
,sum(if(payments.amount>=29.95,4,0)) As Tier4
,sum(if(payments.amount>=24.95<=29.94,3,0)) As Tier3
,sum(if(payments.amount>=19.95<=24.94,2,0)) As Tier2
FROM payments
GROUP BY month(payments.timestamp)
```

The above does not work because MySQL is not evaluating the second part of the condition. Btw it does not cause a syntax error and the select will return results.

Before the above I tried what I was assuming would work like "`amount between 24.94 AND 29.94`" this caused an error. so then I tried "`amount >= 24.94 AND <= 29.94`"

So is it possible to have a range comparison using IF in MySql?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second part of the expression evaluates when you use `AND` -

```
SELECT
 month(payments.timestmap)
,sum(if(payments.amount>=29.95,4,0)) As Tier4
,sum(if(payments.amount>=24.95 AND payments.amount<=29.94,3,0)) As Tier3
,sum(if(payments.amount>=19.95 AND payments.amount<=24.94,2,0)) As Tier2
FROM payments
GROUP BY month(payments.timestamp)
```

I'm not entirely sure why the `between` clause didn't work for you, but the above should do the job.

Answer (score 3):

There is always the [BETWEEN...AND...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

What error did your first attempt give you? It should definitely work. However, note that the second form you have is incorrect syntax. It should be `amount >= 24.94 and amount <= 29.94`.

Comment: you and PConroy are right, duh on my part. I should have added the column name as part of the 2nd condition.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
month( payments.timestamp )
,sum( if( payments.amount >= 29.95, 4, 0 ) )  As Tier4
,sum( if( payments.amount BETWEEN 24.95 AND 29.94, 3, 0 ) ) As Tier3
,sum( if( payments.amount BETWEEN 19.95 AND 24.94, 2, 0 ) ) As Tier2
FROM payments
GROUP BY month( payments.timestamp )
```

This should work also, I tested both with BETWEEN and with > < to make sure they worked the same in one of my queries. So yes, both work.